# Output formatting using setw and setfill

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to get the following output using setw and setfill:

```
OPTIONS:
    <expression>
       The usual operators +, -, *, / and % (remainder)
       Expressions are fixed-point decimal numbers, and
       Parentheses () and corchetes {} may be used for grouping.
```

I'm trying like this:

```
    cout << "OPTIONS:" << '\n';
    cout << "\t<expression>\n";
    cout << '\t' << setw(3) << setfill(' ') << "The usual operators +, -, *, / and % (remainder)\n";
    cout << '\t' << setw(3) << setfill(' ') << "Expressions are fixed-point decimal numbers, and\n";
    cout << '\t' << setw(3) << setfill(' ') << "Parentheses () and corchetes {} may be used for grouping.\n\n";
```

Comment: To print three spaces, just write `<< "   "` or prepend three spaces to your lines of text. `<< setw(3) << setfill(' ')` does something different entirely.

Comment: Can I do it with setw and setfill?

Comment: Not really. `setw` will only append characters if the length of output is less than the chosen width. In order to use `std::setw`, you'd have to pass string length + 3, which is pointless. Just add `<< "   " <<` and forget about this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) is a great tool for printing data with *varying* length in a table format. You specify the width of a column and spaces will get filled in automatically until the specified column width is reached. However, if you need a *fixed* number of spaces it's easier to hard code them: `cout << "   "`. If you need the same indentation many times you might want to define this as a constant

```
auto indent = string(3, ' ');
cout << indent << ...;
```

This allows you to easily adjust the indentation later if needed.